# better way to decrypt with rsa algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, encryption, rsa

I am trying to decrypt an array of ASCII values using the rsa algorithm. So far this is what I have.

```
public void decryption3() {
        double d1 = 6;
        double d2 = 5;
        double d3 = 4;
        int key = 161;
        for(int i = 0; i < three.length; i++){
            BigInteger c1 = BigInteger.valueOf((long)(Math.pow(three[i],d1)%key));
            BigInteger c2 = BigInteger.valueOf((long)(Math.pow(three[i],d2)%key));
            BigInteger c3 = BigInteger.valueOf((long)(Math.pow(three[i],d3)%key));
            BigInteger c4 = c1.pow(8);
            BigInteger c5 = c3.pow(2);
            BigInteger c6 = c4.multiply(c5.multiply(c2));
            BigInteger c = c6.mod((BigInteger.valueOf(key)));
            decryption3.add(c);
        }
    }
```

This calculates the values correctly and outputs the correct quoted, but I am wondering if there is a simpler way to calculate the M in M = C^d(mod 161).
I tried it multiple ways, but this is the only way I have found to work. I know there has to be an simpler way other than splitting up d into multiple calculations. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not use the integer key values directly?

Comment: Use https://www.bouncycastle.org?

Comment: What are those `d` values? It seems you mean the private exponent by that, but why are there three of those. What do those numbers mean?

Comment: I'm not sure why are you trying to implement it yourself but you could easily do it with the Cipher class, here's an example: https://javadigest.wordpress.com/2012/08/26/rsa-encryption-example/

Comment: Yea, you probably want `BigInteger.modPow`

Comment: Harold, I tried switching all the values to big integer type then using c.modPow(d, key); where c is the value from the array getting decrypted, d is the exponent, and key is the mod, but the output is wrong.

Comment: Thanks guys, Harolds solution worked and I can now do the calculation in one step instead of the ugly splitting of d. I needed to grab the int value from the array and convert into a BigInteger for it to work. That was what I was missing. Thanks again!